# Enum constant display name from properties file

Tags: java, enums, eclipse-emf, emf

I have an enum datatype in my EMF model.

This is what I want:

1. I'd like to have nice display names for the enum constants.
2. The display names should be set in a `plugin.properties` file.
3. The mechanism for must integrate well with the EMF system for getting values from properties, so that I can treat all values, enum or not, in a uniform way. That probably means that the solution must use `IItemPropertyDescriptor` somehow.

I can see that enum constants get generated entries in my `plugin.properties` in my EMF Edit project. So there should be some way to get at those names. But I can't figure out how.

I can set the display names in my Xcore model file, but that is not what I want. I want them to be read from my `plugin.properties` file.

It is simple to manually get the enum display names from the properties file. But there should be some way to make EMF handle this. It seems weird that I should have to write special code to handle enum values each time I get a value from the model.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
public enum Constants {
    PROP1,
    PROP2;

    private static final String PATH            = "/constants.properties";

    private static final Logger logger          = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Constants.class);

    private static Properties   properties;

    private String          value;

    private void init() {
        if (properties == null) {
            properties = new Properties();
            try {
                properties.load(Constants.class.getResourceAsStream(PATH));
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Unable to load " + PATH + " file from classpath.", e);
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
        value = (String) properties.get(this.toString());
    }

    public String getValue() {
        if (value == null) {
            init();
        }
        return value;
    }

}
```

And this can be the `constans.properties` file:

```
#This is property file...
PROP1=some text
PROP2=some other text
```

Comment: Note that the question is about Eclipse Modeling Framework. See requirement number 3. This is not a relevant answer for the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get the enum display values using EMF. But with a sever limitation, so I don't consider this to be solved.

The solution works by calling `ItemPropertyDescriptor.getLabelProvider`. The returned label provider is an `ItemDelegator`, which is the only class I have found that has code for reading enum literals from property files. So it's just to call `getText` on that label provider.

```
IItemPropertySource adapter = (IItemPropertySource) adapterFactory.adapt(eObject, IItemPropertySource.class);
IItemPropertyDescriptor descriptor = adapter.getPropertyDescriptor(eObject, feature);
Object propertyValue = descriptor.getPropertyValue(eObject);
Object value = ((IItemPropertySource) propertyValue).getEditableValue(null);    
String text descriptor.getLabelProvider(value).getText(value);
```

The limitation is that `ItemDelegator` "crops" the returned text, by replacing all text after a newline with `...`.

Unfortunately I have to handle multi-line strings in some places in my application, so I still can't handle all features in a uniform way with this solution. So I would really like to find a better one.